# jquery file select event trigger?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, input

This seems like a simple issue, I just can't find the correct answer anywhere so I figured I'd ask all the wonderful folks here at stackoverflow:

I want to create a jquery script that triggers when a user selects a file from their computer.  This just needs to trigger from the file selection act, not completing/submitting the file.  The website is built on rails and is using a file_field to select the file.

Any ideas what the syntax for this would be?  I'm hoping there's something simple and straightforward I can use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
 $("YOUR_FILE_SELECTOR_NAME").on('change',function () {
    alert('FILE SELECTED');
 });
```

if you use J-Query version less than 1.7 you can do:

```
$("YOUR_FILE_SELECTOR_NAME").change(function () {
    alert('FILE SELECTED');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a click event handler on the file_field that gets generated, i.e. in jQuery:

```
jQuery("#id-of-field-that-is-generated").change(function(){...});
```

Since you're using rails, you're probably also using coffeescript (or should be!) in which case you would call:

```
jQuery("#id-of-field-that-is-generated").change, ->
  #do stuff here
```

Comment: Fair enough! you can change 'click' to 'change' and this should work when dropping a file.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to use:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"/>

$('#upload').change( function() {
    if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
        //file selected
    }
});
```